# android:visibility with condition delays before display

Tags: android, data-binding

I'm trying to use android databinding. But I got some problem when I use `android:visibility` with condition. Like `android:visibility="size == 0` `?` `View.GONE : View.VISIBLE`".

When it returns false, it will show this view first, then for a while it turns to gone.

Can I fix this? Or is this the databing's bug?

Answer (score 0):

I ever tried code like this
`android:visibility="@{size==0?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}"`,
but it can not be compiled.I don't know why, maybe it is a bug.

So I using code following instead, firstly, write a Helper.

```
public class Helper {
    @BindAdapter("bind:attr")
    public static void setAttr(View view, Object obj) {
        if (someCondition(obj)){
            view.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

secondly, using custom attr in xml file

```
<View
    ...other attrs...
    app:attr="@{obj}" />
```

> note:
>
> the 'attr' in the annotation must be the same with 'attr' used in xml file.
>
> the View in the static method must be the same with the View in xml file.

My Gradle version and dataBinder version

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.+"
}
```

And, remove other operations unrelated on this view.

Or offer your activity code.

Comment: I tried your way, but it still has that problem.It's not work.(my english is very poor.)

Comment: You shouldn't need the `dataBinder:1.+` line. You should only need to enable data binding with the dataBinding.enabled = true in the android section. see http://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html